# ApiTemporaryUnavailableError

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The `ApiTemporaryUnavailableError` is getting thrown for every single interaction made with the Files API. The only elaboration it provides is:

> Files API is temporary unavailable. Request should be retried soon

I have taken note that the Files API is marked for deprecation, could this mean that it has already been deprecated?

Comment: Our map reduce pipeline are also throwing ApiTemporaryUnavailableError when it is trying to write to the blobstore via the output writer, from today morning...

Checked out their status page, but no information is available on this.

https://code.google.com/status/appengine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may have to do with the fact that the files API is deprecated.

I had the same error trying to push a mapreduce pipeline to the blobstore (as George-Bogdan is having). I decided to finally do the switch I have been avoiding (switching to the [GCS client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/#Python_About_the_Google_Cloud_Storage_GCS_client_library)). Once I finished the switch, my tests have been conclusive, this works properly.

It seems like it's a transient issue on the Google side. But since the Files API is deprecated, I feel safer using the library they actually suggest using now

Comment: Is the new Google policy to simply cut off working apps by shutting down an API without previous announcement (deprecation is not an announcement, because many times Google deprecated an API but still had the replacement marked as experimental)

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck very good question, I have no idea to be honest with you.  To me, deprecated now means "get a contingency plan ready in case it fails".  I noticed this morning my old code (the one using the File API) now works again, so I think it WAS transient. But still, to stay on the safe side, I won't touch that API anymore

Comment: @Julldar I won't touch that API anymore, either... :/

Comment: I have been delaying switching to the GCS client library because the description states: "This is a preview release of the GCS client library. As a result, the library is subject to change and is currently not covered by any SLA or deprecation policy. These characteristics will be evaluated as the library moves towards General Availability."  Very annoying that we don't have any "approved" way of using GCS.

Comment: @Kekito I agree entirely, but at this point it's a deprecated API that has no promise of reliability or using a preview feature and hoping they make it retro-compatible.  I keep a working copy of the Files API's code I made and I will switch as needed between both.