# Google AppEngine backups reporting ApiTemporaryUnavailableError

Tags: google-app-engine, backup

When trying to backup the datastore from the DataStore admin page, backups fail with and error for both blobstore and cloud store targets:

Callstack for cloud store:

ApplicationError: 1 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/backup_handler.py", line 642, in _ProcessPostRequest
    10)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/backup_handler.py", line 492, in _perform_backup
    gs_bucket_name = validate_and_canonicalize_gs_bucket(gs_bucket_name)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/backup_handler.py", line 1803, in validate_and_canonicalize_gs_bucket
    verify_bucket_writable(bucket_name)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/backup_handler.py", line 1763, in verify_bucket_writable
    test_file = files.open(files.gs.create(file_name), 'a', exclusive_lock=True)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/gs.py", line 331, in create
    return files._create(_GS_FILESYSTEM, filename=filename, params=params)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 650, in _create
    _make_call('Create', request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 255, in _make_call
    _raise_app_error(e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 183, in _raise_app_error
    raise ApiTemporaryUnavailableError(e)
ApiTemporaryUnavailableError: ApplicationError: 1

Callstack for blob store:

ApplicationError: 1 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 716, in **call**
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/base_handler.py", line 147, in post
    self.handle()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 1391, in handle
    state)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 1539, in _schedule_shards
    mr_state.writer_state)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/output_writers.py", line 726, in create
    acl=acl)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/mapreduce/output_writers.py", line 640, in _create_file
    return files.blobstore.create(mime_type, filename)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/blobstore.py", line 75, in create
    return files._create(_BLOBSTORE_FILESYSTEM, params=params)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 650, in _create
    _make_call('Create', request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 255, in _make_call
    _raise_app_error(e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/files/file.py", line 183, in _raise_app_error
    raise ApiTemporaryUnavailableError(e)
ApiTemporaryUnavailableError: ApplicationError: 1

Seems to be a problem with the underlying files API which is out of our control. Anyone come across this and have a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may have to do with the fact that the files API is deprecated.

I had the same error trying to push a mapreduce pipeline to the blobstore (as George-Bogdan is having). I decided to finally do the switch I have been avoiding (switching to the [GCS client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/#Python_About_the_Google_Cloud_Storage_GCS_client_library)). Once I finished the switch, my tests have been conclusive, this works properly.

It seems like it's a transient issue on the Google side. But since the Files API is deprecated, I feel safer using the library they actually suggest using now

(answer copied from my own answer [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118195/google-app-engine-apitemporaryunavailableerror))